issues with citing author in texstudio
I've been using texstudio and biblatex for my thesis. When citing authors, I'm using the APA style (Author, Year). Everything was working well until recently when texstudio, for an unknown reason, started putting for some references the first letter of the first name, then the author last name and then the year like in the example hereafter (X. , Author, Year). Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it? It happens regardless of the bibliography entry type (@article, @online).
thanks a lot for your help!

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)

texstudio is just the editor you are using to write the source files, what matters is the markup in your source files about which you have given no information.

Do please tell us which TeX distribution you employ, and when you last updated it. (As @DavidCarlisle has noted in a comment, TeXstudio is merely a front end to a TeX distribution.) Next, please telll us the version numbers of biblatex and of biber that are installed on your system. (You'll find this information in the log file(s).) Maybe their versions are no longer in sync due to an unforeseen issue that happened during an update?
